# How can i stop API array in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

i try to make a trivia app in react js. When user answered the 10th question i like to show the result, which contain a user score. My problem is, that now if you click the 10th question there is an error message, because my getQuestion function can't load from the API more than 10 object/question/. The api data contain 1 array, which contain 10 objects. 
I try to stop the array with an if/else statement, but it doesn't work.
The trivia app in codesandbox:https://codesandbox.io/s/github/SzMariann90/Trivia-Game/tree/development

The problem is in the components/Mquestion.js file

I insert in the getQuestion function:

```
if ( apidata.results[current] === apidata.results.length){
            return score;
```

The code is :

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Score from './Zsgameresult'; 

class Mquestions extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            question:   "",
            answers:    [],
            cor_answer: "",
            current:    0,
            max:        0,
            score:      0,
            apidata:    "",

        };
        this.getQuestion = this.getQuestion.bind(this);
        this.isRightAnswer = this.isRightAnswer.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=26&difficulty=easy')
        .then(response => response.data)
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({
                apidata:  data
            })
            this.getQuestion();
        })

   }


    getQuestion() {
        let { current, apidata,   max, score } = this.state;
         if ( apidata.results[current] === apidata.results.length){
            return score;
        }
    else   if (apidata.results[current].type === "multiple") {
                this.setState({
                    question:   apidata.results[current].question,
                    answers:    [[apidata.results[current].incorrect_answers[0]],
                                [apidata.results[current].incorrect_answers[1]],
                                [apidata.results[current].incorrect_answers[2]],
                                [apidata.results[current].correct_answer]].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5),
                    cor_answer: apidata.results[current].correct_answer,           
                    max:        apidata.results.length,
                    current:    current + 1
                })   
        } 
        else{
                this.setState({
                    question:   apidata.results[current].question,
                    answers:    [["True"],
                                ["False"]],
                    cor_answer: apidata.results[current].correct_answer,           
                    max:        apidata.results.length,
                    current:    current + 1
            }) 
            console.log(this.state.apidata.results[current].type)
        }       
    }

    isRightAnswer() {
        this.setState({
            score: this.state.score + 1,
        })
        this.getQuestion()

    }


    render() {
        let { current, max, score, answers, question, cor_answer,apidata } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h2>Questions {current}/{max} Score {score}/{max}</h2>
                    <p>{question}</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li onClick={event => { cor_answer === event.target.innerText ? this.isRightAnswer()  : this.getQuestion()}}>
                                {answers[0]}
                        </li>
                        <li onClick={event => { cor_answer === event.target.innerText ? this.isRightAnswer() : this.getQuestion()}}>
                                {answers[1]}
                        </li>
                        <li onClick={event => { cor_answer === event.target.innerText ? this.isRightAnswer() : this.getQuestion()}}>
                                {answers[2]}
                        </li>
                        <li onClick={event => { cor_answer === event.target.innerText ? this.isRightAnswer() : this.getQuestion()}}>
                                {answers[3]}
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
               {/*  {apidata && current <10 ? this.getQuestion(question) : '' }

                 {apidata && current === 10 ? (
          <Score score={score}  />
        ) : (
          ''
        )}  */}
            <div>

            </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Mquestions;
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Writing code in `codesandbox` and providing link here would help us to find problem and help you quickly.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, i push the code to codesandbox, and insert the link in the description!

Comment: That's because current is greater than the number of questions. I believe you get 10

Comment: That's because current is greater than the number of questions. I believe you get 10 questions 0-9, once current gets to 10 

apidata.results[current] == undefined because there is no 10th index in the results array

Comment: Thank you everyone for your time! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed your sand box with an alert. The problem was with the structuring of the if statement

https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-gates-kezvn

```
 getQuestion() {
    let { current, apidata, score } = this.state;
    console.log(apidata);
    if (apidata.results.length === current) {
      alert("Your score is : " + score);
      console.log("Complete");
    } else {
      if (apidata.results[current].type === "multiple") {
        this.setState({
          question: apidata.results[current].question,
          answers: [
            [apidata.results[current].incorrect_answers[0]],
            [apidata.results[current].incorrect_answers[1]],
            [apidata.results[current].incorrect_answers[2]],
            [apidata.results[current].correct_answer]
          ].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5),
          cor_answer: apidata.results[current].correct_answer,
          max: apidata.results.length,
          current: current + 1
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          question: apidata.results[current].question,
          answers: [["True"], ["False"]],
          cor_answer: apidata.results[current].correct_answer,
          max: apidata.results.length,
          current: current + 1
        });
        console.log(this.state.apidata.results[current].type);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Dehan de Croos for your time, and your answer, it's working, and now i'm understand why my solution is not working. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for wrong condition. In your case, since the array doesn't contain 10th element, so it is resulting in error. Try below condition, it will work:

```
if (apidata.results.length == current) {
      return this.state.score;
    }
```

So, now `getQuestion` will look like below:

```
getQuestion() {
    let { current, apidata } = this.state;
    if (apidata.results.length == current) {
      return this.state.score;
    }
    if (apidata.results[current].type === "multiple") {
      this.setState({
        question: apidata.results[current].question,
        answers: [
          [apidata.results[current].incorrect_answers[0]],
          [apidata.results[current].incorrect_answers[1]],
          [apidata.results[current].incorrect_answers[2]],
          [apidata.results[current].correct_answer]
        ].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5),
        cor_answer: apidata.results[current].correct_answer,
        max: apidata.results.length,
        current: current + 1
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        question: apidata.results[current].question,
        answers: [["True"], ["False"]],
        cor_answer: apidata.results[current].correct_answer,
        max: apidata.results.length,
        current: current + 1
      });
      console.log(this.state.apidata.results[current].type);
    }
  }
```

Updated Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/white-violet-2g82q

Comment: Thank you for your time, and your answer :)